# Laravel migration return "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly" formed error

Tags: laravel

in my database i have `instagram_accounts` table and i'm trying to create foreign key id of this table with other table as `proxy_connections` named,

```
Schema::create('proxy_connections', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->integer('page_counts');
    $table->integer('account_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('account_id')->references('id')->on('instagram_accounts')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->boolean('status')->default(false);
    $table->string('proxy');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

and `instagram_accounts` table structure`:

```
class InstagramAccounts extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('instagram_accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->string('uid');
            $table->string('fid');
            $table->string('proxy');
            $table->string('avatar');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('page_title');
            $table->tinyInteger('checkpoint');
            $table->mediumText('account_data');
            $table->mediumText('people_data');
            $table->longText('followers')->nullable();
            $table->longText('followings')->nullable();
            $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(0)->nullable();
            $table->string('timezone')->default('Asia/Tehran');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('instagram_accounts');
    }
}
```

for this structure i get error and you should know that i have more data in `instagram_accounts` table, after getting error i try to use another solutions such as :

```
->nullable();
->unsigned();
->unsigned()->nullable();
->unique();
->unique()->nullable();
->unsigned()->index();
```

for all of them i get the error again

**UPDATE**

output of `php artisan migrate --pretend` command:

```
ProxyConnections: create table `proxy_connections` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(191) not null, `page_counts` int not null, `account_id` int unsigne
d not null, `status` tinyint(1) not null default '0', `proxy` varchar(191) not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4
_unicode_ci'
ProxyConnections: alter table `proxy_connections` add constraint `proxy_connections_account_id_foreign` foreign key (`account_id`) references `schedule_instagram_accounts` (`id`) on delete
cascade
ProxyConnections: alter table `proxy_connections` add index `proxy_connections_account_id_index`(`account_id`)
```

Comment: Can you show the migration for `schedule_instagram_accounts` as well?

Comment: Make sure you use the same (exact) type of column for the foreign key  column and the original one

Comment: Add index() and now try:    $table->integer('account_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('account_id')->references('id')->on('schedule_instagram_accounts')->onDelete('cascade');

Comment: @RossWilson i fix simple error on migration and i paste `instagram_accounts` table structure on my post

Comment: @SalmanZafar not any change, i update my post

Comment: can you please run `php artisan migrate --pretend` and put the output of it to the question please

Comment: 1. Do other foreign are correctly created from other migrations? If not (or not checked): check that your database and table are under INNODB engine, not MYISAM. 2. are you sure your migration execution order is correct ? It should be User, then instagram_accounts, then proxy_connections. 3. Could you try creating the foreign after table is created, in a new following Schema::table block ? 4. Does manually adding the foreign from phpmyadmin or else works ?

Comment: @VladyslavStartsev i update post with output of your command

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and it was because of that the foreign key column and the referencing column were not of the same type or length.

So make sure that the column `account_id` from table `proxy_connections` and column `id` from table `instagram_accounts` are of the same type or length.

And same for the column `user_id` from table `instagram_accounts` and column `id` from table `users`.

Hope it Helps you!

Comment: i created `id` for all of tables with `$table->increments('id');` code

Comment: check in the database

Comment: all of them are the same ;( proxy_connections table: http://s6.uplod.ir/i/00934/yx6f1qikuxb7.png    and  instagram_accounts table: http://s6.uplod.ir/i/00934/8dcoqf3p3z32.png

Comment: and what about users table column id, account_id from proxy_connections  and user_id from instagram_accounts ??

Comment: http://s6.uplod.ir/i/00934/zh3c3ljwtje0.png and account_id from proxy_connections and user_id from instagram_accounts is in my prev comment